# Plot differential equation trajectories of a 3-system

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pstricks, asymptote, pst-plot

I was reading about drawing differential equation trajectories with latex, but I wonder... is there a way to graph this?

Consider the system

```
x'=-y+xz^2
y'=x+yz^2
z'=-z(x^2+y^2)
```

The following image I have taken from Perko's book Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems

[image]

Comment: Maybe related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446271, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586198.

Comment: See, e.g., [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263989/125871) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251734/125871).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I have modified the title, sorry, I think it was misunderstood, I want to get the graph of the solutions of a system of differential equations in 3 variables.

Comment: @SandyG I have modified the title, sorry, I think it was misunderstood.

Comment: The general recommendation is to use specialized math software to do the actual calculation. You can then export the result into a CSV file for example and plot it using `pgfplots`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ODEs can be numerically solved with package `pst-ode` (RKF45 method).

The given equation is solved separately for the lower and for the upper half-spaces using initial conditions (1e-9, 0, -1) and (1e-9, 0, 1), respectively. The integration parameter *t* is running from 0 to 35. Solution vectors are output at 500 points for each trajectory, for smooth appearance.

Typeset with `latex`+`dvips`+`ps2pdf` or `lualatex`.

Solution vectors at the output points are written as a table to the text file `XYZ.dat` with option `saveData`, `\pstODEsolve[saveData, ...]{XYZ}{0 1 2}...`. This allows for using a different plotting package, such as `pgfplots`. `Ps2pdf` must be invoked with option `-dNOSAFER` in that case, `ps2pdf -dNOSAFER ...`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-ode,pst-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2.2)%
%\pstThreeDSphere[fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.0,linewidth=0.1pt](0,0,0){1}
% lower half-space
\pstODEsolve[algebraic]{XYZa}{0 1 2}{0}{35}{500}{1e-9 0.0 -1.0}{
  -x[1]+x[0]*x[2]^2 |
  x[0]+x[1]*x[2]^2 |
  -x[2]*(x[0]^2+x[1]^2)
}
\listplotThreeD[linecolor=blue]{XYZa}
\pstThreeDCoor[xMin=-2,xMax=2,yMin=-2,yMax=2,zMin=-2,zMax=2,IIIDticks]
% upper half-space
\pstODEsolve[algebraic]{XYZb}{0 1 2}{0}{35}{500}{1e-9 0.0 1.0}{
  -x[1]+x[0]*x[2]^2 |
  x[0]+x[1]*x[2]^2 |
  -x[2]*(x[0]^2+x[1]^2)
}
  \listplotThreeD[linecolor=green,linewidth=0.4pt]{XYZb}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

---

Animating the integration parameter *t* from 0 to 35:

[image]

```
\documentclass[export]{standalone}

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{pst-ode,pst-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}{10}
\multiframe{71}{i=0+1,rt=0+0.5}{  
  \begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2.2)%
  %\pstThreeDSphere[fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.0,linewidth=0.1pt](0,0,0){1}
  % lower half-space
  \pstODEsolve[algebraic]{XYZa}{0 1 2}{0}{\rt}{500}{1e-9 0.0 -1.0}{
    -x[1]+x[0]*x[2]^2 |
    x[0]+x[1]*x[2]^2 |
    -x[2]*(x[0]^2+x[1]^2)
  }
  \ifnum\i>20
    \listplotThreeD[arrows=->, linecolor=blue]{XYZa}
  \else  
    \listplotThreeD[linecolor=blue]{XYZa}
  \fi
  \pstThreeDCoor[xMin=-2,xMax=2,yMin=-2,yMax=2,zMin=-2,zMax=2,IIIDticks]
  % upper half-space
  \pstODEsolve[algebraic]{XYZb}{0 1 2}{0}{\rt}{500}{1e-9 0.0 1.0}{
    -x[1]+x[0]*x[2]^2 |
    x[0]+x[1]*x[2]^2 |
    -x[2]*(x[0]^2+x[1]^2)
  }
  \ifnum\i>20
    \listplotThreeD[arrows=->, linecolor=green, linewidth=0.4pt]{XYZb}
  \else  
    \listplotThreeD[linecolor=green, linewidth=0.4pt]{XYZb}
  \fi
  \end{pspicture}
}
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

And with slightly modified initial conditions (1e-9, 0.0, 1.0) --> (-1e-9, 0.0, 1.0) for the upper graph:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for giving you the time, your answer is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.